# Github deploy key not working on organization repository

Tags: git, github, deploy-keys

I use deploy key on my repos without any problem... now i want to create deploy key for a repo that belongs to an organization (that I'm a member of), i did it the usual way:

- generate new ssh key:
  `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "test@example.com"`
- adding SSH key to the ssh-agent
  `ssh-add ~/.ssh/key_file`
- add (public key) to the repo deploy keys (github).

but when I try to clone the repo:
`git clone git@github.com:org_name/repo_name.git`
I get this error message:
**"ERROR: Repository not found.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository."**
I tried changing the key multiple times without luck.
not sure what is    happening, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to verify SSH uses exactly that key.

Answer (score 2):

If your key filename is not a default one, I would recommend a ~/.ssh/config file to reference it:

```
Host ghdeploy
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_file
```

That way, you can:

- check if you are correctly authenticated (ssh -Tv gh)
- clone using that new configuration: `git clone gh:org_name/repo_name.git`

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the key is in another repo as a "deploy key" I had done this and was getting the exact same errors..... I made my "id_rsa" as the deploy key on a repo which then disables it from every other repo that you have:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey